# Solve the recurrence equation $T\left(n\right)\:=\:n\:+\:\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\left(T\left(i\right)\right)$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, runtime-analysis

I am trying to find the runtime of:

$T\left(n\right)\:=\:n\:+\:\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\left(T\left(i\right)\right)$

$T(1)= 1$

What is the way to solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\cases{
T_n = n +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T_i\\
T_{n-1} = n-1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}T_i
}
$$

subtracting the second from the firts we have

$$
T_n-T_{n-1}=1+T_{n-1}
$$

or

$$
T_n -2T_{n-1}= 1
$$

with solution (it is easy to solve)

$$
T_n = c_02^n+2^n-1
$$

and considering the initial value

$$
T_n = 2^n-1
$$